# \cite autocompletion in Overleaf shows elements from already-deleted bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, overleaf

I have added a new bibliography `Masterarbeit_V2.bib` to Overleaf and deleted the old one. I also changed the reference to `\bibliography{Masterarbeit_V2}`, cleared cached files and recompiled from scratch.

But when I use the `\cite` command it still offers old entries from the deleted bibliography file. The problem is that some elements are the same in the deleted and the new bibliography file and when I want to cite one of them it only shows me '(??)'. How can I delete the files completely? I think they are still somewhere, otherwise it would not show the old elements ...

Comment: That's probably something to contact the Overleaf helpdesk about. They can access your project to see if there are some leftovers of your earlier file that confuse the auto-complete. Or they can look into whether or not this is a bug.

Comment: (I'm on support staff at Overleaf.) One thing to try is hard-refresh the page, perhaps the old autocomplete results got stuck in a cache. In most browsers this can be done with Ctrl+F5 or Cmd+Shift+R. If this doesn't fix it, please write to us at support@overleaf.com with your project's URL. We can then look at the whole project in the backend to see what might be going wrong.

Comment: That worked, thanks a lot!

Comment: @PaulGessler I'm guessing the question is borderline on-topic here (in any case it might help other Overleaf users). Would you mind turning your comment into an answer so that the question can be marked as answered?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(I'm on support staff at Overleaf.)

One thing to try is hard-refresh the page, perhaps the old autocomplete results got stuck in a cache. In most browsers this can be done with Ctrl+F5 or Cmd+Shift+R. If this doesn't fix it, please write to us at support@overleaf.com with your project's URL. We can then look at the whole project in the backend to see what might be going wrong.